# Render()'s Method different reactions

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I have my render() method with no code.

And I have this action-method:

```
@ProcessAction(name = "viewBook")
public void viewBook(ActionRequest actionRequest,ActionResponse actionResponse) throws SystemException, PortalException {
    long bookId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "bookId");
    Book book = BookLocalServiceUtil.getBook(bookId);
    actionRequest.setAttribute(FinalStrings.BOOK_ENTRY, book);
    actionResponse.setRenderParameter("jspPage", "/html/LibraryPortlet/view_book.jsp");
```

How can I rewrite this "GET" method into `render()` method? I mean I need to run

```
public void render(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse rendeResponse){
    super.render(renderRequest, renderResponse) 
}
```

in the default situation and

```
 public void render(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse rendeResponse){

    \\THIS CODE IS NOT WORKING, IT'S JUST TO SHOW WHAT I WANT!

    long bookId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "bookId");
    Book book = BookLocalServiceUtil.getBook(bookId);
    actionRequest.setAttribute(FinalStrings.BOOK_ENTRY, book);
    actionResponse.setRenderParameter("jspPage", "/html/LibraryPortlet/view_book.jsp");
```

when I need to use viewBook() method. How can I parametrize(?) `render()` method?

---

Update:

For more details I attached one screenshot:

[image: It's my portlet]

Meanwhile in my action.jsp:

```
<liferay-ui:icon-menu>
     <portlet:actionURL name="deleteBook" var="deleteURL">
         <portlet:param name="bookId"
            value="${String.valueOf(book.getBookId())}" />
     </portlet:actionURL>

     <portlet:renderURL name="viewBook" var="viewURL">
        <portlet:param name="bookId"
            value="${String.valueOf(book.getBookId())}" />
     </portlet:renderURL>

     <portlet:renderURL  var="editBookURL" name="viewEdit">
        <portlet:param name="bookId"    value="${String.valueOf(book.getBookId())}" />
     </portlet:renderURL>

<liferay-ui:icon image="add" message="View" url="${viewURL.toString()}" />
<liferay-ui:icon image="add" message="Edit" url="${editBookURL.toString()}" />
<liferay-ui:icon-delete image="delete" message="Delete" url="${deleteURL.toString()}" />
```

In my view_book.jsp:

```
<%@page import="com.softwerke.FinalStrings"%>
<%@page import="com.softwerke.model.Book"%>
<%@page import="com.softwerke.service.BookLocalServiceUtil"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil"%>
<%@ include file="/html/init.jsp"%>

<portlet:renderURL var="backURL">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/view.jsp"/>
</portlet:renderURL>

<liferay-ui:header backURL="${backURL}" title="Back" />

<%
    Book book = (Book) request.getAttribute(FinalStrings.BOOK_ENTRY);
%>


<aui:form>
     <aui:model-context bean="${book}" model="${Book.class}" />
     <aui:input name="bookName" label="Book Name" disabled="true"/>
     <aui:input type="textarea" name="description" label="Description"  disabled="true"/>
     <aui:input name="authorName" label="Author Name" disabled="true"/>
     <aui:input name="price" label="Price" disabled="true"/>        
</aui:form>
```

According to my task I can ***not*** use Action URL here. What should I do???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a command param to the render, so you can split the logic into two or more render methods, depending on the command, or maybe easier, invoke a mvcPath without the need of implementing anything in render(). Include something like this in the jsp with your list of books:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="myBookURL">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/view_book.jsp" />
    <portlet:param name="bookId" value="<%= someBookId %>" />
</portlet:renderURL>

<a href="<%= myBookURL %>">View My Book</a>
```

You just need a view_book.jsp with something like:

```
<%
long bookId = ParamUtil.getLong(request, "bookId");
Book book = BookLocalServiceUtil.getBook(bookId);
%>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't help. I need to transform my viewBook() method into render() method and I don't know how. :(

Comment: My example fits your needs indeed. Just provide mvcPath param in the renderUrl and you don't need to pass through render method. You can get your book in view_book.jsp from the request, as I told you.

Comment: My bad. Really. Thank you, Juan, take 25 rep :D

Comment: sorry, I still can't solve my problem. Could you explain one more time what should I do? I posted all nesessary code in the question

Comment: Keep your default render(). For the new render view just use mvcPath param. It will link to your view_book.jsp, without the need of extra code in render method. I would recommend you to have a look at https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/writing-your-first-liferay-application

Comment: should I delete my viewBook(..) method in .java file?

Comment: Yep. You don't need it. Just provide the view_book.jsp and retrieve your bookid from the request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122197/discussion-between-german-and-juan-manuel-rogado).